# Display Taskbar Icon With Double Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create an icon that when I click at it ==> do some thing, and when I close the window ==> it still in the task bar.

example:

[image]

Thank You.

---

Found Solution and Posted It as Answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a WPF Application to Windows Taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925772/add-a-wpf-application-to-windows-taskbar)

Comment: You can take a tour here: [c# taskbar icon](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=c%23+taskbar+icon&oq=c%23+taskbar+icon&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60j0l3.5423j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank You Guys, I used the `NotifyIcon` control from `System.Windows.Forms` and worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Was Helpful:

```
NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon();
icon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
icon.Visible = true;
icon.DoubleClick += Icon_DoubleClick;
icon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Hello", "This is Tip", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```